# Can Rails unit tests be run on a different environment than test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing

We have a large multi-developer project under Rails in which we are using tests for both models and controllers. Right now the developers have to switch the DB parameters for the 'test' environment to match their local dev environments before running tests. I am wondering if there is a way to run those tests on any environment other than 'test'?

For example we have in database.yml:

```
test:
  database: ...
  host: ...
  username: ...
  password: ...
...
dev-one:
  ...
dev-two:
  ...
```

I can't find anything in the docs on this but maybe I am looking in the wrong place. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What testing framework do you use?

Comment: We are just using the basic Test::Unit, nothing beyond that. Our testing needs are fairly simple and touch more on the controller logic than anything, but the framework won't (as far as I can tell) allow us to run functional tests without booting up the database layer. Note that I am not much of a Ruby/Rails developer so this is all new to me...

Comment: do you have one `database.yml` for all developers? Why don't you let each developer create his/her completely own `database.yml`? I would recommend using different `database.yml` for each developer.

Comment: That seems odd to me, we do have different environments (e.g. dev-one, dev-two above) in a single database.yml, but I haven't seen a need or even a way to have multiple files...and not sure why you would.

Answer (score 1):

As of right now this still does not work. I've submitted an issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21478.

I'll edit this answer with updates

Answer (score 0):

Just a matter of specifying the environment explicitly when you're going to run the tests. You just need a couple of preparations beforehand.

Say your new environment is going to be named "testjohn" (presumably for a developer named John). Then:

1- Copy *config/environments/test.rb* to *config/environments/testjohn.rb*

2- Add the corresponding DB stanza to *config/database.yml* (copy it from the test stanza, rename it, then presumably change the database name, password, and other data).
My (rather simplistic) example uses this:

```
testjohn:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/testjohn.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

3- Run your tests as follows:

```
RAILS_ENV="testjohn" rake db:migrate
RAILS_ENV="testjohn" rake test:units
```

Incidentally, since RAILS_ENV is just an environment variable, you might have a script that sets it beforehand, or even have each developer configuring his own RAILS_ENV variable in his *.profile* or whatever file. That way they just run *rake test:units* and tests automagically execute under their personalized environment.

Comment: Appreciate the response, however, that is exactly what I have tried and it does not work. The environment that you specify in RAILS_ENV is indeed loaded in the context of the rake task, however, once ruby executes your tests it silently switches to your test environment and purges the test database and loads your fixtures.

After more research it seems that this behavior is coded pretty deep into Test::Unit and I am sort of giving up on the possibility. But still very open to suggestions.